# Completion order of CompletableFuture

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

I'm curious to understand the completion order when a CompletableFuture has multiple dependents. I would have expected the dependents to complete in the order they were added, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

In particular, this behaviour is surprising:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            var x = new CompletableFuture<Void>();
            x.thenRun(() -> System.out.println(1));
            x.thenRun(() -> System.out.println(2));
            x.thenRun(() -> System.out.println(3));
            x.complete(null);
        }
        {
            var x = new CompletableFuture<Void>();
            var y = x.copy();
            y.thenRun(() -> System.out.println(1));
            y.thenRun(() -> System.out.println(2));
            y.thenRun(() -> System.out.println(3));
            x.complete(null);
        }
    }
}
```

...results in the the following output...

```
3
2
1
1
2
3
```

Comment: The first line of the internal implementation doc, `A CompletableFuture may have dependent completion actions, collected in a linked stack.` While not in the public spec, it executes dependencies in LIFO order.

Answer (score 0):

All 3 child futures generated by 'x.thenRun()' expression run in parallel, so you cannot expect any particular order of printed numbers.

The same for 'y.thenRun()'.

The expressed order is an implementation feature, can change in the future, and is not supported by the specification.

Comment: The expressions do not run in parallel. There is no asynchronous dispatch occurring here.

Answer (score 0):

So you have *not* chained those `thenRun`, as such there are zero guarantees on the order, but you expect *some* order? Sorry, that's not how it works.

The documentation does not say anything about order of execution in such cases, so whatever you see now in the output:

- is not a guarantee
- can change from run to run (and from java version to version)

It is a little bit hard to prove via code with your current set-up, but just change it to :

```
var x = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
        });
x.thenRun(() -> System.out.println(1));
x.thenRun(() -> System.out.println(2));
x.thenRun(() -> System.out.println(3));
x.join();
```

And run this let's say `20 times`, I bet that at least once, you will not see `3, 2, 1`, but something different.

Comment: The order of execution of asynchronous calls is irrelevant here, I'm only referring to the order of synchronous calls.

Comment: @Vaci but the specification does not tell you about _any_ order, so you can not assume one. It is a `stack` under the hood, but that is an implementation detail.